# Xamarin Forms Picker Value Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, picker

When binding to a picker, you can use `ItemDisplayBinding` to bind the displayed value, but I do not see a way to map each item to a selection value.  Because of this, I'm having to write some very convoluted code to keep my pickers in sync with data source changes.

Original Model

```
// NOTE: this implements INPC, just abbreviated for clarity
public class DataModel
{
  public ICollection<DataItem> Items;
  pubilc DataItem SelectedItem;
}
```

Original Picker:

```
<Picker Title="Select Item..." 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"></Picker>
```

New Model

```
// NOTE: this implements INPC, just abbreviated for clarity
public class DataModel
{
  public ICollection<DataItems> Items;
  public ICollection<string> ItemNames;
  public DataItem SelectedItem;
  public string SelectedItemName;
  public DataModel()
  {
     this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => 
     {
       // I feel like I shouldn't have to do this...
       if(StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(e.PropertyName, nameof(Items)))
       {
          if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(this.SelectedItemName))
          {
             this.SelectedItem = this.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(x.Name, this.SelectedItemName));
             if (this.SelectedItem == null) { this.SelectedItemName = null; }
          }
       }
  }
}
```

New Picker:

```
<Picker Title="Select Item..."
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemNames}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItemName}"></Picker>
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<Picker Title="Select Item..."
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        ItemValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItemName}"></Picker>
```

I do not need a reference to the item, I need a property off of it.  In this way, when the Items collection changes, it automatically reselects the correct item if it's still present.  I find that I'm adding a second collection everywhere with just the properties I want to choose and doing all this mapping.  Every other platform I've worked on, this is pretty straight forward, so I feel like I have to be missing something with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I think you don't need to do this.The `SelectedItem` property data binds to the `SelectedItem`(in your original model) property of the connected view model, which is of type `DataItem`. Therefore, when the user selects an item in the Picker, the `SelectedItem` property will be set to the selected `DataItem` object automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do this.The SelectedItem property data binds to the SelectedItem(in your original model) property of the connected view model, which is of type DataItem. Therefore, when the user selects an item in the Picker, the SelectedItem property will be set to the selected DataItem object automatically.

You could test it in its `SelectedIndexChanged` event like:

```
<Picker Title="Select Item..." 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
    SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </Picker>

 private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker picker = sender as Picker;
        DataItem dt = picker.SelectedItem as DataItem ;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Name); // you will see when you select a item,the SelectedItem will be changed automatically
    }
```

And i suggest you use  `ObservableCollection<Item> Items`, so it will automatically update your `Items` when it changes.

Comment: I understand SelectedItem would bind there and my DataItem object would be stored there.  However, the backing list objects change so they are no longer reference equal, but they would have the same name property or id property.  This makes it so the item is not reselected because the reference is different.

Comment: @MPavlak Yes,It depends on how you change the data, if you replace an existing item, even if the name is the same,because their references are different.

Comment: Correct, that's what's happening and what I want to avoid.  I am binding to a name property which would reselect properly if it allowed project of values just like displayed name.  Most other frameworks allow this so I'm very surprised that Xamarin.Forms has nothing for this.